# Comparing a 2D array with Keyboard input

Tags: java

My output is:
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
Enter flight number to search:

I am getting data from a .txt file which is then stored in a 2D Array
Can you help me with the null situation please?

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
        String search;
        FileReader fr = null;
        LineNumberReader lnr = null;

        String list[] = new String[160];

        String plane[][] = new String [20][8];//Creating an array in an array
        int p,i;
        try{
            //create new reader
            fr = new FileReader("Data.txt");
            lnr = new LineNumberReader(fr);
            String input = null; 
            for(p=0; p<20; p++)
            for(i=0; i<8; i++){
                input = lnr.readLine();
                if (input != null) {
                    plane[p][i]=input;
                }
            }
            //for(p=0; p<1; p++){
            //  for(i=0; i<8; i++)
            //    System.out.println(plane[p][i]);
            //}
            }catch(Exception e){
             // if any error occurs
             e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
             // closes the stream and releases system resources
             if(fr!=null)
                fr.close();
             if(lnr!=null)
                lnr.close();
        }

        System.out.println("Enter flight number to search: \t");
        search = Keyboard.readString();
        for(p=0; p<20; p++){
            if(search == plane[p][0]){
               System.out.println("Information about flight: "+plane[p][0]);
               System.out.println("----------------------------------");
               System.out.println("Flight Number: "+plane[p][0]);
               System.out.println("Air Line: "+plane[p][1]);
               System.out.println("To: "+plane[p][2]);
               System.out.println("From: "+plane[p][3]);
               System.out.println("Departure Time: "+plane[p][4]);
               System.out.println("Estimated Time: "+plane[p][5]);
               System.out.println("Status: "+plane[p][6]);
               System.out.println("Distance: "+plane[p][7]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is `input` variable is null. Print input variable to cross check.

Comment: I modified your program just enough that I could run it. I cannot persuade it to print `null`, so I assume your problem is somewhere else. My modifications were: Instead of `Data.txt` I filled in a text file on my computer. I commented the for loop back in that prints `plane[p][i]` to see if it gave any nulls, it didn’t. And I had to comment out the lines after `System.out.println("Enter flight number to search: \t");` because I din’t have the `Keyboard` class that you seem to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly believe this is because your `Data.txt` file is empty. `lnr.readLine()` will return

> `null` if the end of the stream has been reached

You try a `null` check in your code, but it doesn’t really help because your array `plane` contains `null` from the creation and will continue to contain `null`s until you put something else in there.

It seems that already the first call to `lnr.readLine()` returns `null`, which is why I think the reader is at the end of the file from the start, that is, the file is empty.

Comment: Actually now the output is:
Enter flight number to search:
KM514 (Then I enter a plane number)
(Then the terminal stops)

Comment: I think that the problem is when it comes to the If Statement (the comparing part). Isn't it?

Comment: Well spotted! I agree and I think the answer is here: [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java#513839) (follow the link).

Comment: So how should I write it?

Comment: Never mind, solved the problem.
Thanks for the reference :) Appreciate it